# How to mail a birt Report In SpagoBI in CSV format

Tags: email, birt, spagobi

How to mail a birt report in SpagoBI in Csv Format i have tried to use schedular to schedule a mail by default it is working to generate html(.txt) format,

But how to do that for csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using the csv type in outputType parameter instead of txt.